# Enum Error in C "Unknown Type"

Tags: c, enums

I keep getting "Unknown type name 'place' even though I wrote the enum correct I can not see the error on what I am doing wrong. thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
void pass(place x);

typedef enum{

house, second

} place;

int main()
{

pass(house);

return 0;
}

void pass(place x){

 if(x == house){
  printf("We are in a house \n")
  }else if(x == second){
  printf("We live in the second house \n");
 }

 return;

 }
```

Comment: If you look closely at the error message, you'll see it points to a line *before* the actual enum declaration...

Comment: I.e. how does the prototype `void pass(place x);` know what a `place` is, when you haven't aliased it yet.

Comment: Oh ok that fixed it thanks m8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `enum place` declaration is fine. The problem is you're defining a function with place before the existence of `place` is known. Change the order and define your place enum first, before you `pass()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


typedef enum{
   house, 
   second
} place;

void pass(place x); // This function forward declaration must be after you defined place.

int main()
{ /* .. */ }
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)